# Umbraco.config is being deleted when republishing the entire site

Tags: umbraco7

While i'm trying to republish entire umbraco site, the `umbraco.config` file is getting deleted.

Once it is deleted, if I try to republish the entire site, a new `umbraco.config` file is not created.

Due to this, i'm not able to see the changes I made in site.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Does the IIS appool process have the appropriate rights to write to the App_Data directory?

Comment: yes, It has write permission

Comment: Can you find anything in the log files? Located in App_Data/Logs

Comment: no, Last two lines of the log are "Loading content from disk cache..." and " Loading content from database..."

Comment: hm that's weird, are you sure the connection string in the web.config is correct? When did this problem occur? When first installing Umbraco or perhaps after migrating to another server?

Comment: Connection string is fine. Problem arise after migrating the Umbraco database to another server.